# Working on my CSS in RoR assets precompile issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working with RoR, devise, bootstrap and I have to rake assets:precompile each time I modify my css in order to view them. Is there a workaround to this ?
Because I somnehow can't detach by daemon from my command, it is extremely time consumming.

Comment: You can try clearing the assets with `rake assets:clean`. Also, did you make any changes to your development.rb file? Which version of Rails are you using as well?

Comment: Are you running your app in development mode?

Comment: did not make any chances to development myself, no. Latest version of rails. 
I guess in my development mode, yes.

Comment: production mode actually, sorry.

Comment: you can look for guard module to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the contents of `public/assets`. That'll cause sprockets to rebuild your assets on each page view in development mode. Don't develop in production mode.

Comment: I go from production to dev by simply destroying public assets ?

Comment: No, you actually run your app in production mode by passing a specific flag to your app when you start it up, depending on your webserver. By default, rails will refuse to dynamically compile assets in production mode. You generally run `rake assets:precompile` prior to a production deployment, which creates the assets in public/assets/